# How can i make changes to java code built with maven and see the changes without building a new jar?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dropwizard

I am using **idea intellij** and I am working on a **drop wizard** project that is built with maven.

Is there any way I can see my code changes reflect live without having to **build a new jar each time**?

Comment: Just pressing the Run button does not work?

Comment: `JRebel` might be exactly what you need.

Comment: it starts a build process to create a new jar, is there anyway to change the code on the fly?

Comment: @vikingsteve. is there a free solution available :) ?

Comment: Click on jrebel download and you can get a free trial.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Maven builds jars (or other artefacts). Your asking the wrong thing. Change your code and run a test and Idea will compile your changes and execute them via the test. You only want to run the maven build when you want to produce the jar/war for deployment to a server (which can also be set up to hot-deploy your code, but this is a more complicated concept).